# What is type declaration for in definition of Nat in shapeless?

Tags: scala, shapeless, peano-numbers

This is the definition of `Nat` in package `shapeless`:

```
   trait Nat {
     type N <: Nat
   }

   case class Succ[P <: Nat]() extends Nat {
     type N = Succ[P]
   }

   class _0 extends Nat with Serializable {
     type N = _0
   }
```

What are the `type` declarations for ? 
Once removed it seems to me that the definition works equally well.

Answer (score 4):

They're used where `Nat` is the target type of an implicit conversion from a literal `Int` ... see [here](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/syntax/hlists.scala#L89), for example, in the definition of the `Int` indexing method for `HList`,

```
def at(n : Nat)(implicit at : At[L, n.N]) : at.Out = ...
```

Here the intention is that the method is invoked with a literal `Int` argument,

```
(23 :: "foo" :: true :: HNil).at(1)
```

The argument is converted to a `Nat` by an implicit macro which is able to inspect the compile time argument tree and construct the corresponding `Nat` value. We can then refer to the type member `N` of `n` and use it as an index for the `At` type class which extracts the desired element from the `HList`.